# Why is spring boot ignoring my schema.sql file?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
src/main/resources/schema.sql
```

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/tmp/vuls
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I've been all over SO and the correct procedure for H2 database creation apparently changes with every Spring Boot release, because there are various and sundry answers out there that aren't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering issues with initializing your H2 database using the `schema.sql` file in your Spring Boot application. Here are a few things to check:

1. **Configuration Properties**: Verify that your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file contains the correct properties to specify the SQL script and other database configuration details.

To use H2 embedded:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.sql.init.mode=embedded

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Then to access to h2 console  :

http://localhost:8080/h2-console

2. **Check Logs**: Look for any error messages or warnings related to database initialization in your application logs. This can provide valuable insights into why the schema initialization is not happening as expected. Pay attention to any exceptions or warnings related to database connectivity or schema initialization.
3. **Dependencies**: Double-check that your project dependencies are correctly configured. Since you're using H2 as an embedded database, ensure that the H2 dependency is included in your project's build configuration (`pom.xml` for Maven or `build.gradle` for Gradle).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you continue to encounter problems, providing specific error messages or logs can help in diagnosing the issue further.

Comment: Thanks Faraj ... Do you have samples of log messages generated when it is working? Because I'd to identify the Spring classes involved so I can debug them.

Comment: 2024-03-14T07:16:27.460-05:00  WARN 27416 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.

Comment: Spring Boot's application.properties**:

   you can use Spring Boot's built-in logging configuration properties to set the logging level. Add the following to your `application.properties` file:
   
   ```properties
   logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was more of a Batch issue than a Boot issue. What worked for me was adding the application property 'spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always'